# cluster installation stuck at "installation in progress" in cloudera manager

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I have installed Cloudera manager 5.4 version into ubuntu OS. When I try to install cluster using cloudera manager it got stucked  "**Installation in progress**" with no errors.

I could see only two errors from `/var/log/cloudera-scm-server/cloudera-scm-server.log`

```
2015-05-12 19:11:42,715 ERROR main:org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: relation "cm_version" does not exist
  Position: 21

2015-05-12 19:16:58,585 ERROR main:com.cloudera.server.web.cmf.cloud.EC2MetadataFetcher: Request to EC2 metadata failed: I/O error: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 2000 ms; nested exception is org.apache.commons.httpclient.ConnectTimeoutException: The host did not accept the connection within timeout of 2000 ms
```

can someone pls help

Comment: Are you running this on AWS?

Comment: im running it on ubuntu 12.04 local machine

Comment: At what exact point did it get stuck? What stages have you cleared? Can you ssh between the nodes on the cluster?

Comment: its single node cluster and this issue happening after we provide details of user and rsa key,pass phrase etc which is in 4th step.

Comment: Looks to be an issue with your DNS or IP loopback setup.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments looks to be a DNS/ IP loopback issue.

Update your /etc/hosts file like the following:

I updated the /etc/hosts file to look like this and the inspector worked.

```
> 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
> xx.xx.xx.xx mc.domain.com mc
```

Substitute xx.xx with your ip & mc.domain.com with appropriate values for you machines hostname. HTH.

Comment: I  have followed the steps given by you. but still im facing the same issue